# How to increment so can I get the next column value not the new row in list view?

Tags: java, android, listview, increment, android-database

**How can I get the next column value not the new row?**

Im using listview to display information of the selected user from the spinner.

What shows up: Firstname, Firstname, Firstname

Should be instead: Firstname, Lastname, Email, etc.

Im thinking about adding i++ but seems not to be working

```
  public void myMethod(String user) {

    ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor data = db.getListViewAccountrequestinfo();
    if (data.getCount() == 0) {

    } else {

        while (data.moveToNext()) {


            theList.add( data.getString(0) );
            ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, theList);
            lvinfo.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are setting adapter inside loop . Thats a total disaster. Put that code outside of loop . And have a local variable increment it on each iteration and use it further for your problem .

Comment: Please specify what the problem is or add the errors(if any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive got it already. Here is my new working code after 4 hrs LOL

```
 public void myMethod() {

    ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();


    Cursor data = db.getListViewAccountrequestinfo(spnpending.getSelectedItem().toString());
    if (data.getCount() == 0) {

    } else {


        if (data.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                theList.add("Username: " + spnpending.getSelectedItem());
                theList.add("First name: " + data.getString(1));
                theList.add("Last name: " + data.getString(2));
                theList.add("Contact: " + data.getString(3));
                theList.add("Email: " + data.getString(4));

                ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, theList);
                lvinfo.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            } while (data.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> > Listview should display the rows in database, not columns.
>
> Because `data.getString()` takes parameter as `int columnIndex`

so when you increment its value(columnIndex), it will give **Next Column** value not the new row.

Refer [Cursor.getString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int))